# add extra value to kwarg list

Tags: python

Suppose there is the following external module and its spelled out like this:

**module1.py**

```
X = [1,2,3]

def test_func(keyword_list=X):
    return keyword_list

test_func()
```

In another file I am trying to add another item to the kwarg `X` where ill be making my call and that will be here:

**my_file.py**

```
from module1 import test_func

test_func()
...
```

Is there any way concise way of adding an extra list item to my kwarg in my initial call to `test_func`. I know technically I could something like the following:

```
from module1 import test_func, X

test_func(keyword_list=X + [4])

[1,2,3,4]
```

Is there anyway to do this without importing `X` directly from `module1.py`?

**Edit** `module1.py` is an open source module that I can't directly change.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? I mean, you want to use default value of the function, add something to it, and then call it again? Like u dont know how the default value look like, right? So I think this would be kind of strange behavior. Maybe if you could give me more reasonable example I would be able to help u, but right now I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by this.

Answer (score 1):

Use another keyword arg:

```
def test_func(keyword_list=[1,2,3,4], additional_list=[]):
    return keyword_list + additional_list

print(test_func())
print(test_func(additional_list=[5]))
```

Should produce

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Or use a wrapper function:

```
def wrapper_test_func(additional_list=[]):
  return test_func(module1.X + additional_list)
```

Comment: `test_func` comes from a public module that I can't directly rewrite.

Comment: see the edits in my answer -- use a wrapper function so that you don't have to non-elegant stuff in every call

Answer (score 0):

It seems one way to enable the scenario would be to have your test_func api take two lists...

```
def test_func(user_keywords=None, default_keywords=X):
    # merge them
    # more stuff...
```

I am sure there are ways to reflect over the method and get the default args using the `inspect` module and methods such as `inspect.getargspec` but that seems like a hassle that can be avoided by accommodating intended use cases in the method signature in the first place.

Comment: If you can't change test_func, take a look at the inspect module to lookup arg default values.